# How can I debug stored procedure step by step in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

How can I debug stored procedure step by step in SQL server...??
I put a break point in stored procedure and start debug , but I got an error like

> "Unable to start T-SQL Debugging . Could not attach to SQL Server
>   process on 'WCHN-210'  Click help for more information"...

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s0fk6z6e(v=vs.100).aspx) about the steps required to enable TSQL debugging?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do:

1. Script the procedure. You should get something like this:

   ```
   DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[ups_Test]
   GO

   SET ANSI_NULLS ON
   GO

   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
   GO

   CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ups_Test]
   @ParameOne int,
   @ParameTwo nvarchar(10)
   AS
   BEGIN
       -- Your code
   END


   GO
   ```
2. Delete the "drop/create","begin/end" etc statements.
3. Add a 'DECLARE' in front of each parameter and a value if it does not have default.

   ```
   DECLARE @ParameOne int=10,

   DECLARE @ParameTwo nvarchar(10)=''

   -- Your code
   ```

That's all - execute the statement and see where is the problem.

Comment: @a4aabi01 I am showing you the right way to debug SQL store procedure - this is not C/C++ and using some debugging tools does not seem reasonable. Have you got a problem to understand the technique that I have described?

Comment: "Unable to start T-SQL Debugging . Could not attach to SQL Server process on 'WCHN-210' Click help for more information".. I want reason for this issue..

Comment: This error appears when the account that you are using has not enough rights. Your user account must also be a member of the system administrator role in SQL Server.